# Given a String of Buckets (alphabets). Find the cost (possibly minimal) to bring all the buckets at the base

Tags: string, algorithm, data-structures, hash

Bob is a construction worker who does mathematics for increasing his efficiency. He is working on a site and has n buckets of cement-lined up with different characters (a – z) marked upon them. He has a strict command from the senior that he cannot change the order of the buckets.

Before starting his work, he has been given a string **s** of length **n** in which the character at position **i** (1 <= i <= n) gives us the mark on the **i'th** bucket. He can only carry one bucket at a time and bring it back to the base site. In each round, he has a criterion on which bucket to pick up. He will take the bucket with the smallest character marked upon it (a<b<z) and if there are multiple buckets with the smallest character, then he will take the one closest to the base.
The cost of picking up a bucket B is the number of buckets he passes through while walking from the site to get B (the bucket which he picks is also included). In each round, the cost accumulates. Find the final cost incurred by Bob while completing his job.

**Constraints**

`1 < t,m < 10^5`

The sum of n over all test cases does not exceed 10^6

**SAMPLE INPUT**

2
badce

**SAMPLE OUTPUT**

7

**Explanation**

- badce - Firstly Bob takes the second basket with mark 'a' and adds 2 to the cost.
- bdce - Then he takes the first basket with the mark 'b' and adds 1 to the cost.
- dce - Then he takes the second basket with the mark 'c' and adds 2 to the cost.
- de - Again he takes the first basket with the mark 'd' and adds 1 to the cost.
- e - Again he takes the first basket with the mark 'e' and adds 1 to the cost.

The total cost becomes 7 units.

I have tried to code in **Python** but giving **TLE** for some cases.
Here is my approach-->

```py
n = int(input())
s = input()
count_array = [0] * 26
for i in range(n):
    count_array[ord(s[i])-97] += 1

alphabets = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']
    
ans = 0

for i in range(26):
    while count_array[i] > 0:
       idx = s.index(alphabets[i])
       ans += idx + 1
       if idx > -1: s = s[0:idx] + s[idx+1:]
       count_array[i] -= 1
    
print(ans)
```

I am looking for an optimized approach that takes **O(nlogn)** or **O(n)** time complexity. Thank You.

Comment: As a hint: Can you think of a way to find the distance sum for one letter in O(n) time? Rather than modifying the string, is there a way to keep track of how many previous indices have been removed at each index?

Comment: You want a min deque for this.  A hash will not help.

Comment: Here is a good example and explanation of a [max deque](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sliding-window-maximum-maximum-of-all-subarrays-of-size-k/). A min deque is exactly the same, except the max comparisons are reversed to Mins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This runs in `O(n)`. For every char, check how many previous chars will be transported later.

```python
def get_cost(s):
    result = 0
    seen = [0] * 26
    for c in s:
        idx = ord(c) - ord('a')
        result += 1 + sum(seen[idx+1:])
        seen[idx] += 1
    return result
```